# file.nextInt exits my nested for loops

Tags: java, file-io, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I am trying to read in data from a text file and put it into a 2d array. I have the text file and I have tested my program and know that it reads the data but the following loop exits whenever I try to put the data into my array.

```
for(int i = 0; i<9; i++){
  for(int j = 0; j<9; j++){
    System.out.print("hey");
    grid[i][j] = file.nextInt();
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

[**edit**]
Sorry for the initial lack of information i only posted the snippet which i was having trouble with.
`grid` is initialized higher up in the code as `int[][] grid;` and the file is a `.txt` that contains each number that is meant to be in the `grid` seperated by a single space.

Comment: What do you mean by "exits"? Any exception being thrown? How did you declare/initialize `grid`?

Comment: What is actually `file`, what type of object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int[][] grid;` doesn't actually allocate any memory, maybe you wanted

```
int[][] grid = new int[9][9];
```